# DAO Bean Package

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

Currently I use a JPA package that contains Entities and DAOs. The DAOs are singleton EJBs.

As far as I know, the EE specification requires to use two packages for this: One JPA package and one EJB package for the DAOs.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

How is rest of your project organized?

If you have separate packages for each framework part then you should split them. On the other hand if you have more domain-driven packaging (similar features in single package) then you can keep them in single one.

- If it is an old project you should favor consistency and follow rules used by previous programmers
- If you are just starting and have a choice you should at least consider domain-oriented packaging. It is more maintainable when program gets bigger.